# (non)Zero elements in an SPD matrix A lead to (non)zero elements in L where L is the Cholesky decomposition matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Given an SPD matrix $A$ and Cholesky decomposition $A = LL^T$.

Prove that $A(i,j) = 0$ means that $L(i,j) = 0$ and that $A(i,j) \neq 0$ means that $L(i,j) \neq 0$

I've been messing around with the formulas that determine the elements of the L matrix for too long now. I thought about proving this through induction and through a contradiction but nothing worked. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not true. Consider
$$
A=LL^T=\pmatrix{
1&1&-1&1\\
1&2&0&1\\
-1&\color{red}{\mathbf0}&3&0\\
1&\color{forestgreen}{\mathbf1}&0&3}\ \text{ where }
\ L=\pmatrix{
1&0&0&0\\
1&1&0&0\\
-1&\color{red}{\mathbf1}&1&0\\
1&\color{forestgreen}{\mathbf0}&1&1}.
$$
It is true, however, if $A$ is both entrywise positive and positive definite and you are talking about the entries of $L$ in the lower triangular part.

Comment: Then I formulated my question wrong, sorry. What you mentioned is exactly what I'm talking about. However, it is given that $A$ is SPD and we define $f_i(A)$ as $f_i(A)$ = min($j : a_i_j$ \neq $0$) for $i = 1, ... , n$. Show then that $f_i(A) = f_i(L)$. I thought that what I asked would directly lead to the proof of this aswell, but apparantly not.. Edit: I'm very inexperienced with LaTeX so apologies for poor formatting.

Comment: @S.Crim *That* statement is true, though. Fix $i$ and let $J=f_i(L)$. Since $l_{ii}>0$, we must have $J\le i$. Therefore, when $j\le J(\le i)$, we have $$a_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^nl_{ik}l_{jk}=\sum_{k=1}^{\min(i,j)}l_{ik}l_{jk}=\sum_{k=1}^jl_{ik}l_{jk}=\sum_{k=J}^jl_{ik}l_{jk}.\tag{1}$$It follows immediately that $a_{ij}=0$ when $j<J$ (because the RHS of $(1)$ is an empty sum) and $a_{iJ}=l_{iJ}l_{JJ}\ne0$. Hence $f_i(A)=J=f_i(L)$.

Comment: Thanks alot. Why are you able to turn the $n$ above the sum into $min(i,j)$ though? I figure that you can turn the $k = 1$ into $k = J$ because all elements before $J$ are zero in the $L$ matrix, I can't figure out the first step though. Edit: Is it because $L$ is lower triangular? I think I figured it out!

Comment: @S.Crim Do you mean the step turning the upper limit $n$ to $\min(i,j)$? Yes, it's because $L$ is lower triangular.

Comment: I think I fully understand now. Thanks alot!

Comment: One last thing actually.. sorry. Could you explain why we only look at $j \le J$ and not also $j > J$?

Comment: @S.Crim We want to show that $a_{iJ}$ is the first nonzero entry on the $i$-th row of $A$. Once this is proved, there is no need to look at other $a_{ij}$s behind $a_{iJ}$.